# Ubuntu server hanging and can't find cause

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linode

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 512mb VPS server running on Linode. I have it setup to serve about 6 Wordpress powered websites.

For a few weeks now it has crashed daily, 2-3 times. Linode automatically reboots the machine, but if I disable that I either can't SSH in at all, or if I do, the server responds extremely slowly.

Just last night I switched over everything from Apache to nginx, but that didn't help.

Looking at the log files, the only thing I've found is that the last entry is almost always

```
Mar 28 06:05:01 cappicola CRON[10852]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
```

Although sometimes that is several minutes before the reboot. Sometimes I also find

```
Mar 28 06:09:01 cappicola CRON[10860]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
```

The only other entries in the log file are postfix and fail2ban related warnings. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second log string is caused by your cron activity which looks for idle php-sessions and kills them. To get over this issue, you should edit your `/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime` file as specified here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865303/debian-based-systems-session-killed-at-30-minutes-in-special-cron-how-to-overri).

If it doesn't help, you should try to get more statistics on how your system perform before the reboot. To deal with this, please look the answer here (http://www.unix.com/linux/110432-system-getting-crashed.html).

Comment: Thanks -- it was actually your second tip that did the trick. I found two processes running wild that shouldn't have even been running in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any monitoring like Zabbix? It will be usefull to log into some stats. You san also use sar(1). How about load average?

Answer (score 0):

fail2ban is most likelely the one that freezes the machine.

Try disabling all rules / fail2ban at all and check the reaction. I guess it has something to do with python going nuts, when running as server. Also notice, that the approach to read logfiles can be a degression, in case the logfiles get very big and the system has to load the files into the memory to grep out certain matches.

Also: check the filesystems: `[sudo] shutdown -Fr now`